# Can you override a function from a generically typed object?

Tags: java, performance, hash, hashmap

I have a class in Java that stores generic `Object` types in a HashMap:

`private final Map<Object, NetworkMarker> packetMarker = new WeakHashMap<>();`

The `packet` Object is very large and the map has very high throughput, so the hashing of the packets alone takes up an absurd amount of cpu cycles, and I am curious if it's possible to minimize this, or I just need better hardware.

Would there be a way to override, despite being a generic Object class with no wrapper, the `hashCode` function to make it more efficient, or perhaps extend the hashmap to enhance the `#get()` method? Or any other method that I am overlooking!

Cheers!

EDIT for clarification: The `packet` Object is not typed. It is of the type `Object`. It's being passed in from an external source, so I cannot assign a type.

Comment: You should explain more about the "`packet` Object". What class is it? Why is the `Map` not `Map<Packet, NetworkMarker>`? What is it about hashing the packet which makes it so expensive? What does the `packet` `equals` method look like. I don't understand which class's `hashCode` you are considering overriding.

Comment: the `packet` object is literally a generic `Object`. It's being passed in from another source, so I cannot assign or cast it to a type. Every method is stock `Object#`

Comment: If it is actually an Object then its hashCode implementation should be fast. But do you mean that its concrete type varies and is only bounded by Object, in which case @shmosel's wrapper sounds like a good plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always wrap it in another class that caches the hash code:

```
class CachedHash {
    public final Object cached;
    private Integer hashCode;

    public CachedHash(Object cached) {
        this.cached = cached;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return cached.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (hashCode == null) {
            hashCode = cached.hashCode();
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```